# Theorem 3.1 in the chapter 8 of Differential Topology by Hirsch

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold, orientation

In Differential Topology by Hirsch, I find

> **3.1 Theorem** Let $M$ be a connected $n$-manifold and $f,g$: $D^k \hookrightarrow M$ embeddings of the $k$-disk, $0 \leq k \leq n$. If $k = n$ and $M$ is orientable, assume that $f$ and $g$ both preserve or both reserve, orientation. Then $f$ and $g$ are isotopic.
> If $f(D^k) \cup g(D^k) \subset M \setminus \partial M$, an isotopy between them can be realized by a diffeotopy of $M$ having compact support.

and I'm having trouble understanding "we can further assume that $f$ and $g$ both preserve or reverse orientation as embeddings into the orientable manifold $U$" in this proof.

The assumptions before the relevant section are that $\partial M = \emptyset$ and $(U, \phi)$ is a chart on $M$ such that $\phi(U) = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\phi(f(0)) = 0$, and we have $f(D^k) \cup g(D^k) \subset U$.

The following is a quotation from the proof of the theorem.

> If $M$ is orientable this follows from the hypothesis. If $M$ is not orientable we can
> replace $f$, if necessary, **by an isotopic embedding obtained by isotoping $f$
> around an orientation reversing loop based at $f(0)$.**

What operations do the bolded sections represent?　Thank you.

P.S.:
I think the opration represents that transforming $f$ by isotopy such that isotopy that overhangs $U$. But how do I confirm that it is possible?

Comment: Take the Mobius strip as $M$ and let $U$ be an interior chart on the Mobius strip. If $f : D^2 \to U$ is a disk which is orientation reversing, consider the isotopy of $f$ (as a map to $M$!) to $\bar{f} : D^2 \to U$, $\bar{f}(x) = f(-x)$ given by pushing the disk that is in the image of $f$ around the center circle of the Mobius strip. Visually, the effect is that the disk swaps its front and back face (try with coin). This can always be done for any nonorientable $M$, since one can always find an orientation-reversing loop (one which lifts to a path in the orientation double cover).

Comment: @BalarkaSen I understood it sensibly. So we are using $\partial M = \emptyset$ here? And do you have some references for "nonorientable manifold has an orientation-reversing loop"?

Comment: Just prove it yourself. If every loop is orientation-preserving, this tells you that you can orient all of $M$ by fixing a point $p_0$ and choosing an arbitrary path to $p$, orienting $T_pM$ compatibly with $T_{p_0}M$. The hypothesis shows that this is well-defined. See Hirsch's discussion on the bottom of p. 104.